# rake assets:precompile, Command failed with status (137):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I am trying to precompile assets using assets:precompile command but i am getting below error.

> ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
>   ** Execute assets:precompile /root/jruby-1.7.9/bin/jruby /root/jruby-1.7.9/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production
>   RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
>   ** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
>   ** Invoke assets:cache:clean (first_time)
>   ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute assets:environment
>   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute environment
>   ** Execute assets:cache:clean
>   ** Execute assets:precompile:all rake aborted! Command failed with status (137): [/root/jruby-1.7.9/bin/jruby /root/jruby-1....]
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:55:in `create_shell_runner' org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in`call'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:41:in`
>   sh'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:41:in`
>   ruby'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.3.11/lib/turbo-sprockets/tasks/assets.rake:24:in
>   `ruby_rake_task'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.3.11/lib/turbo-sprockets/tasks/assets.rake:33:in`
>   invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3-0.3.11/lib/turbo-sprockets/tasks/assets.rake:50:in
>   `(root)' org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in`call'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in
>   `execute' org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in`each'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in
>   `execute'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in
>   `invoke'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in`
>   invoke_task'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `top_level' org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in`each'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `top_level'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`
>   run_with_threads'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in
>   `top_level'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`
>   run'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`
>   run'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in
>   `(root)' org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1099:in`load'
>   /root/jruby-1.7.9/bin/rake:23:in `(root)' Tasks: TOP =>
>   assets:precompile

My gem file is as below

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
#gem 'mysql2'
 gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter', '~> 1.3.0'
 gem 'jruby-openssl'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.2.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyrhino'
# gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise', '3.2.2'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 2.2.3'
gem "instagram", "~> 0.10.0"
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'rack-cache', :require => 'rack/cache'
gem "dragonfly", '~>0.9.15'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
gem "lazyload-rails"
gem "spreadsheet"
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
# gem "ruby-mcrypt"
gem "koala","~> 2.0"

group :development, :test do 
    gem 'hirb'
    gem 'pry'
  gem 'awesome_print', '~> 1.6.1'
#  gem 'better_errors', '~> 1.1.0'
#  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

My Gemfile.lock is as below

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.14)
      actionpack (= 3.2.14)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (3.2.14)
      activemodel (= 3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.14)
      activemodel (= 3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.5)
      activerecord (>= 2.2)
    activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.3.5)
      activerecord-jdbc-adapter (~> 1.3.5)
      jdbc-mysql (>= 5.1.22)
    activeresource (3.2.14)
      activemodel (= 3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
    activesupport (3.2.14)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.3.8)
    arel (3.0.3)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    atomic (1.1.14-java)
    awesome_print (1.6.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2-java)
    bootstrap-sass (3.0.2.1)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0147)
    builder (3.0.4)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    delayed_job (4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
    delayed_job_active_record (4.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      delayed_job (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
    devise (3.2.2)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    dragonfly (0.9.15)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    faraday (0.8.9)
      multipart-post (~> 1.2.0)
    faraday_middleware (0.9.0)
      faraday (>= 0.7.4, < 0.9)
    ffi (1.9.8-java)
    hashie (2.0.5)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hirb (0.7.3)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    instagram (0.10.0)
      faraday (>= 0.7, < 0.9)
      faraday_middleware (~> 0.8)
      hashie (>= 0.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    jdbc-mysql (5.1.28)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-datatables-rails (2.2.3)
      jquery-rails
      sass-rails
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jruby-openssl (0.9.4)
      bouncy-castle-java (>= 1.5.0147)
    json (1.8.1)
    json (1.8.1-java)
    koala (2.0.0)
      addressable
      faraday
      multi_json
    lazyload-rails (0.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.5.2)
    multi_json (1.8.4)
    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    newrelic_rpm (3.9.9.275)
    nokogiri (1.6.1)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.1-java)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.10.1-java)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
      spoon (~> 0.0)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.14)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.14)
      actionpack (= 3.2.14)
      activerecord (= 3.2.14)
      activeresource (= 3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.14)
    railties (3.2.14)
      actionpack (= 3.2.14)
      activesupport (= 3.2.14)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.1)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ruby-ole (1.2.11.7)
    sass (3.2.13)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    simple_form (2.1.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spoon (0.0.4)
      ffi
    spreadsheet (0.9.7)
      ruby-ole (>= 1.0)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    therubyrhino (2.0.2)
      therubyrhino_jar (>= 1.7.3)
    therubyrhino_jar (1.7.4)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    thread_safe (0.1.3-java)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbo-sprockets-rails3 (0.3.11)
      railties (> 3.2.8, < 4.0.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.2.0)
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.4.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    whenever (0.8.4)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.4)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)

PLATFORMS
  java

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (~> 1.3.0)
  awesome_print (~> 1.6.1)
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.0.2.0)
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  daemons
  delayed_job_active_record
  devise (= 3.2.2)
  dragonfly (~> 0.9.15)
  hirb
  instagram (~> 0.10.0)
  jquery-datatables-rails (~> 2.2.3)
  jquery-rails
  jruby-openssl
  koala (~> 2.0)
  lazyload-rails
  newrelic_rpm
  pry
  rack-cache
  rails (= 3.2.14)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  simple_form
  spreadsheet
  therubyrhino
  turbo-sprockets-rails3
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  whenever
```

Please someone help me, i am getting the error from inside the gem, i could  not able to get what is status (137). I searched in internet i could not able to find any error with status (137). please help me out.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. I deploy my app to AWS OpsWorks, and it keeps failing with `Ran bundle exec rake assets:precompile 2>&1 returned 137`.

Answer (score 0):

if got any error in precompile of  assets then firstly try to run this command

```
rake assets:clobber
```

then precompile the assests

Comment: I ran above command but it gave `Don't know how to build task 'assets:clobber'` error.

Comment: did  you have the  gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie' if not install it then run it

Comment: Again I am getting the same above error which i mentioned in the question.

Comment: did you type rake assests:precompile or not

Comment: Yes i type rake assets:precompile itself.